# Create a property with a call policy - boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have the following C++ classes that I would like expose to python.

```
class PlainOldData
{
     ...
};

class FancyClass
{
public:
    const PlainOldData& GetMyPOD() {return myPOD;}
private:
    PlainOldData myPOD;
};
```

Because I want my python classes to be pythonic, I would like expose myPOD as a property. However, when I try to do the following:

```
// expose with boost::python
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymod)
{
    class_<PlainOldData>("PlainOldData", init<>());

    // this fails
    class_<FancyClass>("FancyClass", init<>())
        .add_property("myPOD", &FancyClass::GetMyPOD);

}
```

I get the following error: `error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<T>'`

But, if I try to specify a call policy, such as:

```
    class_<FancyClass>("FancyClass", init<>())
        .add_property("myPOD", &FancyClass::GetMyPOD, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>());
```

I get an incredibly long error message.

Is it possible to expose this function as a property; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you pastebin the long error message?  Does it help to make the function itself `const`?  `const PlainOldData& GetMyPOD() const {return myPOD;}`

Comment: It makes no difference. If you look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html - you will see the definition of class_::add_property doesn't have an argument for a call policy, that is probably the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to how Python's [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) is passed Python callable objects, the [`boost::python::class_::add_property()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) function can accept Python callable objects that can be created with [CallPolicies](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/CallPolicies.html), such as those returned from [`boost::python::make_function()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html#make_function-spec).

For example, the property in the original code could be exposed like:

```cpp
class_<FancyClass>("FancyClass", init<>())
  .add_property("myPOD", make_function(&FancyClass::GetMyPOD,
    return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()));
```

---

Here is a complete minimal example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class egg {};

class spam
{
public:
  const egg& get_egg() { return egg_; }
private:
  egg egg_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<egg>("Egg");
  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    .add_property("egg", python::make_function(&spam::get_egg,
      python::return_value_policy<python::copy_const_reference>()))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> assert(spam.egg is not spam.egg) # unique identities as spam.egg
                                     # returns a copy
>>> egg1 = spam.egg
>>> assert(egg1 is not spam.egg)
>>> egg2 = spam.egg
>>> assert(egg1 is not egg2)
```